# jQuery fancybox json error in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, fancybox-2

I'm hoping you can help me here.  I'm trying to load a form into a modal window (using fancybox2) and I've hit a wall in IE8.  I'm using Fiddler web debugger to check my ajax request, and under the JSON tab I get the error

```
WARNING:Illegal/Unquoted identifier 'if' at position 3.
Illegal/Unquoted identifier 'lt' at position 6.
```

This is obviously caused by checking the IE version

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

However, I don't know how I can get around this?  I've tried specifying an element of the target page, adding my IE8 check before the IE7 check and a couple of other things, but nothing has worked yet.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What happens to the page in without using fiddler? What does the browser console say? Have you tried debugging without fiddler by using the browsers' debugger?

Comment: Using IE8s console I do not get anything back at all.  Not a sausage

Comment: Do you load the form from an AJAX call? or is it inline? What's response you receive if it is AJAX...

Comment: are you using fancybox in `iframe` mode? if not, you should because you are trying to read the `<head>` elements. If using `ajax` then those conditions should be in the parent page.

Comment: I was loading the form through fancybox 2 ajax functionality, but I've abandoned it for JFK's iframe idea (Thanks JFK!).  However, it has left me with a new issue.  This page is for a competition, and starts with a textarea for their answer.  The user then clicks the submit button, which kicks off fancybox.  I was using the afterLoad callback to copy the answer the user entered into the answer field of the form.  Now that I am using an iframe that no longer works.  Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this now?

Comment: @dannyslade : you still could use ajax but don't set any styles, scripts and/or conditional comments in the loaded page but in the calling page. Then the ajaxed page will inherit what it needs from the parent page.